# How to set previous value when cancelling a drop-down list change event using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript

I am looking how to set previous value when cancelling a drop-down list change event using JavaScript only. But I am weak in JavaScript.

Could you please change below fiddle in pure JavaScript only.

http://jsfiddle.net/w9JYX/14/

Or if possible could you please share new Fiddle using JavaScript only.

```
    <select id="dropdownId">
    <option>Option A</option>
    <option>Option B</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdownId2">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you want to achieve. 
Also, In JSFiddle you have added jquery instead of Javascript.

In Javascript if you want to change value you need to do something like

```
var val1 = document.getElementById("").value
```

Also, Consider using `if` and `else` statement to solve your problem

Comment: I got that fiddle. And I want to change that jquery code into pure javascript only.

Comment: Hello.. could you please help me regarding this?